# Counting steps in Python

Tags: python

Functions are confusing me majorly.

What is wrong with my code here, I'm sure there are plenty things, but elaborate on what I'm doing wrong, please.

2000 steps is 1 mile, input is number of steps, output is miles walked.

```
def steps_to_miles(user_steps):
    steps = input();
    mile = steps / 2000
    return user_steps

print('%0.2f' % user_steps)
```

Comment: what's the expected input and output?, also I don't see you calling that function anywhere, also you would want to cast `input()` to integer via `int(input())`, get rid of `user_steps` as input, and call the function as `steps_to_miles()` So `def steps_to_miles():
    steps = int(input())
    mile = steps / 2000
    return mile`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: Input is number of steps, output is the miles walked.

Comment: Strange to me that this is marked as off-topic. The desired behavior of the code seems crystal clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems**

1. Input returns a string, which you cannot do arithmetic on
2. Python doesn't use semicolons as line terminators
3. You're returning the number of steps, not the number of miles
4. You're not calling the function in the print statement
5. Your conversion function shouldn't ask for input

**Try this**

```
def steps_to_miles(user_steps):
    miles = int(user_steps) / 2000
    return miles
```

**Example**

```
>>> steps = input()
4321
>>> print( '%0.2f' % steps_to_miles( steps ) )
2.16
```

Comment: Python actually uses semicolons as line separators, but they are not mandatory. Try for yourself `print('Does python use semicolons as line terminators?');print('Yes it does !')`

Comment: Your function argument is `user_steps` but your first line says `miles = int(steps) / 2000`?

Comment: Agreed, my comment was poorly-worded. The point is that it is a violation of the Philosophy of Python (regarding superfluous characters),

Note that semicolons in Python are not statement terminators, as they are in other languages; they are compound statement delimiters.

For example `if 2 == 1: print( "unequal"); print( "ok" )` won't print anything.

Comment: Good point, @DeveshKumarSingh. I will fix inline.

Comment: @Stefan I didn't know that one, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

for calculating steps code will be like this:

```
def steps_to_miles():
    steps = int(input('Enter Steps: '));
    mile = steps / 2000
    return mile

print('You Walked',steps_to_miles(),'miles')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function waits for user input - if you feed it no arguments in your code it will show no message and wait for your input.

It does not represent the function input - that is already represented by `user_steps` parameter.

The `user_steps` is defined only within the scope of your function (the indented part) so the `user_steps` variable in your `print` statement is not the same variable.

I think you meant to write it like this

```
def steps_to_miles(steps):
    return steps / 2000

user_steps = input("Please enter the number of steps walked:\t")
print("You have walked %0.2f miles !" % steps_to_miles(user_steps))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like

```
def steps_to_miles():
    steps = input();
    mile = steps / 2000
    return mile

print('%0.2f' %steps_to_miles())
```

This should work.